# Key saved but not correctly

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I was able to save my key on GitHub. (It does not end in .pub).

When testing if this was done correctly and using the '`ssh -T git@github.com`' code, there is something off.

The terminal asks me if I want to continue, and I wrote 'yes', then a pop-up box asking for a password came up... I input nothing and clicked "unlock", which resulted in the bottom code saying "Permission denied". (see screenshot).

[image: screenshot]

I'm not sure what to do here--I have followed the instructions multiple times.
Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: You put your key in github that did not end with `.pub`? So you added your secret key to github?

Answer (score 0):

When you [add your SSH key to GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account), that would be the one ending with `.pub`.

Then, double-check the correct private key is used with:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

It would ask for a passphrase only if you have created the private key with a passphrase.
If you did, make sure to [add your key to the agent first](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent).
Check also your [`~/.ssh` permissions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1232326/5470).